# get config settings from database to share across app in angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, slim

I am trying to figure out the best practices way to retrieve my config settings from my database table and use these across my app. I am using PHP Slim for the RESTful API. I am not sure which is better? Use $rootScope or a service, and the best way to approach it?

Example using SLIM. If I want all the fields of the configs table I run this inside a controller:

```
Data.get('config').then(function(data){
    configs = data.data;
});
```

currently I have a service but it is not working:

```
app.factory('dataShare', function($rootScope, $log, $http, Data) {

  var configs = {};

  Data.get('config').then(function(data){
    configs = data.data;
  });

  return configs;

});
```

I need to be able to get any of these fields inside my postCtrl.

Comment: Does `Data.get()` return an object with a `$promise` property?

Comment: It uses SLIM for the http request. Data.get('configs')... does a get request to the db for the configs table

Comment: I resolved the q issue. your code was missing the $ but I still get undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a few things from the previous answer including showing how the print out should be called since were continuing the asynchronus behavior in to your controller.

```
  app.factory('dataShare', function($rootScope, $q, $log, $http, Data) {

      var configs= {};
      configs.getconfigs=function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          Data.get('config').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data.data);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
      }



    return configs;
    });
```

should then be able to call this inside your controller as long as you have q injected and the page this controller controls has

```
<script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/2.0.3/q.min.js"></script>
```

then call this.

```
dataShare.getconfigs().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: deferred is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing a terrible job of proof reading my answers, I forgot to assign $q.defer() to deferred originally. that now happens first line of the function.

Comment: AWESOME! thank you! that worked... can you explain why it needs to be this way so I can better understand?

Comment: Sure, so that Data.get function call is making an asynchronous call to get some data. your code originally fires that function call off and then moves on down the list of things to do, specifically to the return configs; line meaning that by the time the asynchronous call comes back you've already returned the empty configs object.                    That $q.deferred function creates a promise then waits for that promise to resolve which doesn't happen until your original data.get function is able to carry out its callback. once it does resolve then you hit the return line of your code.

Comment: thank you. one more question if you don't mind. in my configCtrl i now don't need to get the data from the db a second time so I want to utilize the service. the old approach was `Data.get('config').then(function(data){
         $scope.configs = data.data;
         $scope.buttonText = 'Update Config';
         $scope.today($scope.configs);
    });` I tried this new approach: `dataShare.getconfigs().then(function(data){
        $scope.configs = data.data;
        $scope.buttonText = 'Update Config';
        $scope.today($scope.configs);
    });` but it does not work

Comment: in the code you have posted in this comment, the top function call passes in "data" directly from the get request and that allows you to ask for data.data, in my answer up there I have already grabbed data.data out of the response and returned it so that "data" in .then(function(data){  }) is already equal to data.data. so you can do $scope.configs =data.

Comment: Why not just return the promise made by $http?

Answer (score 0):

You're destroying your reference.

```
app.factory('dataShare', function($rootScope, $log, $http, Data) {

  var service = {};

  Data.get('config').then(function(data){
    service.configs = data.data;
  });

  return service;

});
```

Then in your controllers/other services where you use dataShare use them like dataShare.configs.

Comment: When I try to run something like this: `$log.log('get configs called from postCtrl - ' + dataShare.configs);` in postCtrl I get undefined